# I want to start my spring boot application aftet Mysql is up and running

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have one java spring boot application which uses mysql DB . I want to start my spring application only after mysql is up and running . ( mysql takes 40-60 sec to up ) . Please suggest how to achieve it .

here is the compose file :

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    mysql:
        networks: 
            - my-network-1
         
        image: mysql:latest
            
        environment: 
             MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
             MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
             MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
        expose: 
            - "3306"
        
 
    my-spring: 
 
        depends_on: 
            - mysql
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfile.dockerfile
        networks: 
            - my-network-1
        expose: 
            - "8080"
 
networks: 
    my-network-1:
        driver: overlay
```

Here is docker file :

```
FROM  openjdk:8u252-jdk
 
 
ARG JAR_FILE=/somepath/jar.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} my.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","my.jar"]
```

currently getting connection refused error.

Thanks

Adarsha

Answer (score 1):

Use this under mysql part on docker compose file

```
healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
    interval: 1m30s
    timeout: 20s
    retries: 10
```

so your compose file should be like this

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mysql:
    networks: 
        - my-network-1
     
    image: mysql:latest
        
    environment: 
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
         MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
         MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
    expose: 
        - "3306"
    
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
        interval: 1m30s
        timeout: 20s
        retries: 10

  my-spring: 

    depends_on: 
        - mysql
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: dockerfile.dockerfile
    networks: 
        - my-network-1
    expose: 
        - "8080"

networks: 
   my-network-1:
     driver: overlay
```

If above solution doesn' work, I would recommend to go through this docs https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: healthcheck is not  supported in version 3 and above

Comment: @Adarsha https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck

Comment: I have checked and health check will not work with version 3+ . Their documentation may be wrong .